# Serialize and deserialize a certificate

Tags: ssl, .net-core, serialization

**Question**: using .NET, is it possible to serialize AND deserialize a certificate? If so, how is it done?

**Background**: I have a service that I need to develop. This service needs to know for sure which workstation/server is calling it.

Each of the computers at my company has a certificate on it that identifies the machine and is signed by an internal Certificate Authority (CA).

I somehow need my service to get that certificate, verify that it was signed by our internal CA and then get the machine name it was designated for.

So far, I have two half baked ideas on how to do this.  The first, and focus of this question is to serialize and deserialize the certificate. I would have the client serialize it and then send the serialized string along with the request. The server would deserialize it and check that it was signed by our internal CA.

My only problem is that I am not sure it is possible serialize and deserialize a certificate (it seems it could be a security risk if people could just serialize the certificate and pass it around as if it was theirs).

But if it is possible, I can just pass the the certificate in to the service as a parameter. So far, I have found options that allow for a serialization, but not for deserialization.

Using .NET, is it possible to serialize AND deserialize a certificate?  If so, how is it done?

Comment: An X.509 certificate is already a serialized data structure. The structure is defined in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) and the serialization method is ASN.1 No need to serialize and deserialize it again.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should just be using SSL (https) and you'll get everything that you need here for free.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - As I understand it, SSL is for the server to give a certificate for the client to trust.  I am looking for the Client to give a certificate for the server.  My other idea was mTls.  Which may work, but I don't really know how to set it up.

Comment: Certification can work in the other direction as well. Client needs to send the server a signed certificate that the server can then validate against the CA. I forget the details, but this is fairly standard. What transport mechanism do you use, WCF?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - Alas no. We switched to ASP.Net Core when WCF did not make it into .Net.  We are using simple restful calls in ASP.Net Core. (.Net 6)

Comment: People are forgetting that certificates are **public**, and getting one proves nothing at all. I can send you a certificate that says I'm google, yet I'm not google. Certificates must be used in a sensible protocol, like TLS, that achieves the security requirements of your system.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk -I assumed that the issuer could not be faked. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0